# Query usando Mongoose in Nodejs sempre retorna null mesmo dentro de assíncrono método

Tags: javascript, node.js, query, mongodb, mongoose

Eu estou tentando recuperar um documento em meu Database usando Mongoose in Node.js mas ele sempre retorna Null. 
Meu problema antes era o método assíncrono , mas agora tudo está sendo executado dentro dele. E eu so estou tentando imprimir o documento recuperado do Database, mas sempre retorna isso :

```
#session from the database ++++++++++++++++ null
```

Essa é minha funçao:

```
function isAuthorized(sessionID, sessionIDtype, callback){
    var id = "'"+ sessionID+"'"
    sessions.findOne({'sessionIDtype': id}, function(err, sessionDoc){
        if(err) return handleError(err);
        if(sessionDoc != undefined){ 
            log.d("session from the database inside no if != undefined++++++++++++++++", sessionDoc)
            if(sessionDoc.date < new Date()){ //fix validation on data, expires needs to be < new Date
                callback(sessionDoc);
            }else{
                callback(undefined);
            }
        }else{
            callback(undefined)
        }
        log.d("session from the database ++++++++++++++++", sessionDoc)
    }); 
}
```

Está retornando isso no terminal:

```
#session from the database ++++++++++++++++ null
```

e nunca entra neste if:

```
if(sessionDoc != undefined)
```

Eu acho que o erro está na query, mas eu já tentei isso:

```
sessions.findOne({'sessionIDtype': sessionID}, function(err, sessionDoc){
```

e isso:

```
var query = {}
query["'"+ sessionIDtype +"'" ] = sessionID;
sessions.findOne(query, function(err, sessionDoc){
```

mas se eu substituo os valores a query é executada. Com esse codigo funciona:

```
 sessions.findOne({'googleUID': '12314'}, function(err, sessionDoc){
```

segundo a Documentação do Mongoose:
fonte :http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

O problema não são as aspas no valor :

```
 sessions.findOne({'key': 'value'}
```

O problema são as aspas da chave: para a query funcionar a primeira palavra tem que esta entre aspas,mas o valor nao precisa esta. Exem:

```
sessions.findOne({'key': value} //Isso funcionaria, eu ja testei.
```

O problema eé que eu recebo o nome do identificador e o valor pela funcao acima. Entao, eu posso so substituir o valor pelo parametro que eu recebo, mas o identificador nao. Exem:

```
sessions.findOne({'parametro1': value}
```

Nao posso fazer isso acima. Nao funcionaria.

Eu posso criar um if para cada caso, mas o codigo ficaria muito feio. Exem:

```
funcao(param1, value){

 if(param1 == "googleUID")

sessions.findOne({'googleUID': value}

} //Isso funcionaria
```

Mas e se eu tiver 10 possibilidades de identificadores? 10 if's não da!

então, como colocar aspas  no identificador?

Comment: já tentou sem as aspas na sessionID ? Geralmente o framework de dados cuida disso para ti.

Comment: Vc pode comentar aqui a parte que vc esta se referindo? Qual framework? Desculpe, sou nova nisso.

Comment: Vc esta certo. Isso funcionaria: session.findOne({'key':variable}) sem aspas no valor, mas o problema e a chave que n sei qual  é.Atualizei a questao.

Comment: E realemente me perdi no que você escreveu. "O problema são as aspas da chave", se tentar com `{'sessionIDtype': sessionID}` o que acontece?

Comment: @Caputo , vc esta certo isso funcionaria. Mas a key que eu tenho no documento n é 'sessionIDtype', sessionIDtype é a variavel que armazena o nome da minha key.Pode ser 3 diferentes nomes. Posso fazer 3 ifs, mas e se eu tivesse 10 diferentes nomes? esse é o problema. Em vez de repetir o codigo 3 vezes queria fazer somente uma vez.

Comment: E se tentar: `var condicao = new Object();` e depois `condicao[param1] = value;` e por último `sessions.findOne(condicao)`

Answer (score 1):

Crie o objeto com os parâmetros primeiro, e use a notação de colchetes para ter uma chave dinâmica:

```
function isAuthorized(sessionID, sessionIDtype, callback){
    var parametros = {};
    parametros[sessionIDtype] = sessionID;
    sessions.findOne(parametros, function(err, sessionDoc){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isto aqui vai funcionar:

```js
sessions.findOne({sessionIDtype: sessionID}, function(err, sessionDoc){
   ...
});
```

Edição após seu comentário:

Que tal fazer assim então:

```js
var criteria;

if (...) {
  criteria = {
    fbUID: '1234'
  };
} elsif (...) {
  criteria = {
    googleID: '4567'
  };
else {
  criteria = {
    twitterID: '7890'
  };
};

...

auth = isAuthorized(criteria, cb);

...
function isAuthorized(queryCriteria, callback){
    sessions.findOne(queryCriteria, function(err, sessionDoc){
```

Comment: Nao funciona. So funcionaria assim com aspas : sessions.findOne({'key': sessionID}). O problema e q a palavra key pode ser 3 palavras diferentes. Tipo "fbUID", "googleID", "twitterID"